# "dataloader" does not match the tag data of the "targets"

Tags: python, yolo

I have a problem,as follows:

The dataloader does not match the tag data of the targets!
[image]
This is targets:
[image]
This is dataloader:
[image]

In Yolov7's train.py. The target data for targets must come from the data in the dataloader, but why can't I find the data for targets in the dataloader?

After Debug, In `train.py`, the `dataloader` does not match the tag data of the `targets`!